# How to Reload slick (slider/carousel) jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

i have **2 buttons** with same function, that's to Get data from API then convert to html then append it using jQuery to `<div>`. Last, show it using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) jQuery plugin to show HTML element as slider.

However, after click 1st button, if i click 2nd button (or vice versa), **the `slick` (slider) does NOT work anymore**.

The **Javascript** Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /*
    Description  : Handle Day Button Event
    */
    $('.dayList').on("click", function(event)
    {
            var dayChild = $(this).attr('id');

            //::refresh day lline
            $('.hour-to-hour-line').empty();    
            getHourList(dayChild,function()
            {

                /* 
                The Slick
                */
                $('.hour-to-hour-line').slick({
                  dots: false,
                  infinite: false,
                  speed: 1000,
                  slidesToShow: 6,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  focusOnSelect: true,
                  arrows: false,
                  slickSetOption: true
                }); 
          });   
    });
});
```

The **HTML** Code :

```
<div id="monday" class="dayList" data-daycount = "1" tabindex="1"> Monday </div>
<div id="tuesday" class="dayList" data-daycount = "2" tabindex="2"> Tuesday </div>
<br/>
<div id="hour2" class="hour-to-hour-line"></div>
```

The **Javascript** Code, `getHourList()` function :

```
function getHourList(day,callback)
{
    //::convert day to dayCount
    var dayCount = 0;
    switch(day) {
        case "monday":
            dayCount = 1;
            break;
        case "tuesday":
            dayCount = 2;
            break;      
    }

    //::fetch data from API
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/api/1.0/schedule/items?day='+dayCount,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic WS8fkn5344WN8==");
        },
            success: function (data) 
            {
                //::refresh <div class='hour-to-hour-list'> template
                $('.hour-to-hour-line').empty();                

                //data definition
                var iCounter_1          = 1;
                var iCounter_2          = 1;
                var iCounter_2_next   = 1;
                var timer = [];

                //::exctract time from array=>data
                jQuery.each( data.item, function( key, val ) 
                {                                   
                    timer[iCounter_1] = val.time;       
                    iCounter_1++;           
                });

                //::exract time from array=>timer
                jQuery.each( data.item, function( key, val ) 
                {                   
                    var time         = val.time;        
                    var parent_id = "hour_"+iCounter_2;
                    var hour_id    = "this_hour_"+iCounter_2;
                    var next         = iCounter_2 + 1;

                    $html = 
                    "<div id="+parent_id+" class='fl hour-focus'>"+
                        "<div id="+hour_id+" class='fl kurohige-prev jaman' data-time="+time+">"+time+"-"+timer[next]+"</div>"+
                        "<div class='fl line-0'></div>"+                    
                    "</div>";

                    $('.hour-to-hour-line').append($($html));       
                    iCounter_2++;       

                });
                if (callback)
                {
                    callback();
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Anybody have solution for this ?

Comment: You should try to use something like this: `$('.hour-to-hour-line').slickRemove(0)` and  `$('.hour-to-hour-line').slickAdd(getHourList(dayChild));`

Comment: Could we have the content of `getHourList` function ?

Comment: Read the docs.. To destroy this plugin you have to use `$('.your-slider').slick('unslick');` not `$('hour-to-hour-line').unslick()` (search for **Destroy**) in http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Hi @MoshFeu i've tried it, the results from firebug is "TypeError: a[f].slick is undefined"

Comment: Hi @EdenSource there'is no slickRemove(0), i got error by trying it...

Comment: You're right, the syntax found in the doc is this one: `$('.hour-to-hour-line').slick('slickRemove',0);`

Comment: A. When you develop I recommend to use the unminified version so you will can understand better the problems. B. I think you should check why you can't destroy it. My guess is that this is related to your problem.

Comment: @EdenSource stil error, in firebug : `TypeError: a[f].slick is undefined`

Answer (score 30):

Here's the working code

> tested for slick version 1.8.1

```
$('#slick-slider').slick('refresh');
```

Comment: In my case refresh did not work and used `resize` method  and it worked for me `jQuery(".popup-slider").slick('resize');`

Comment: Am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined`

Comment: Which is your slick version?

Comment: @TomSawyer maybe you can try like $('.slick-slider').eq(0).slick('refresh');

Comment: @MihirBhatt it doesn't work. correct way is `$('.photos').not('.slick-initialized').slick()` , it re-slick all un-initialized elem after an ajax load.

Answer (score 5):

The code below works for me

```
$('.my-slider')[0].slick.refresh()
```